# Kendo UI Scheduler Event Link

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Is it possible to open an url when an event is clicked? I want to route my users to an url contains details related to event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just handle the `change` event of your scheduler like this:

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
      change: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();                           // prevent the default action
        if (e.events.length > 0) {                    // if true then user clicked an event, not an empty slot
        window.location.href = 'stackoverflow.com';   // replace with the desired url
        }
      },
      // ... set other properties ...
});
```

The `e.events` is an array that has list of clicked events.

[Kendo Scheduler Change Event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#events-change)

Comment: Ahmad many thanks for your reply. Can I reach you via mail or another way?